# Vue Component Library - Can't import from dist

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, rollupjs

I've been trying to get a Vue Component Library setup for a couple days. I've looked over several tutorials and read through code of some popular existing UI libraries. My issue has come down to this:

My library is called @company/vue-components

I install my library into a project with npm:

```
npm install @company/vue-components
```

I then attempt to register my library as a plugin with Vue:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueComponents from '@company/vue-components';

Vue.use(VueComponents);
```

I try to use my component in the vue-cli generated About.vue page (Called EButton):

```
<template>
    <div class="about">
        <h1>This is an about page</h1>
        <e-button color="primary">Click this button</e-button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
};
</script>
```

But I get an error:

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <e-button> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option
```

If I go back to where I registered the plugin, I can make this one change and it'll work:

```
import VueComponents from '@company/vue-components/src/index';
```

So, I guess I am not building my dist package correctly, as that's what is referenced when I simply use "@company/vue-components". If I print each variable in the console, I can see that the import for the distribution bundle does not include the "install" function, but the source import does:

[image]

Here is all the source code I can think of that's relevant. This is a mash-up of using the vue-sfc-rollup cli tool and copying the Buefy library setup.

#### EButton.vue

```
<template>
    <button class="button" v-bind="$attrs" v-on="$listeners">
        <slot></slot>
    </button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'EButton',
    inheritAttrs: false
};
</script>
```

#### EButton/index.js

```
import EButton from './EButton.vue';

const Plugin = {
    install(Vue) {
        Vue.component(EButton.name, EButton);
    }
};

let GlobalVue = null;

if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    GlobalVue = window.Vue;
}
else if (typeof global !== 'undefined') {
    GlobalVue = global.Vue;
}

if (GlobalVue) {
    GlobalVue.use(Plugin);
}

export default Plugin;

export {
    EButton
};
```

#### components/index.js

```
import EButton from './EButton';

export {
    EButton
};
```

#### src/index.js

```
import * as components from './components/index.js';

const install = function(Vue) {
    if (install.installed) {
        return;
    }
    install.installed = true;

    for (let name in components) {
        Vue.use(components[name]);
    }
};

const Plugin = { install };

let GlobalVue = null;

if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    GlobalVue = window.Vue;
}
else if (typeof global !== 'undefined') {
    GlobalVue = global.Vue;
}

if (GlobalVue) {
    GlobalVue.use(Plugin);
}

export default Plugin;
```

#### rollup.config.js

```
import vue from 'rollup-plugin-vue';
import buble from 'rollup-plugin-buble';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import replace from 'rollup-plugin-replace';
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';
import minimist from 'minimist';

const argv = minimist(process.argv.slice(2));

const baseConfig = {
    input: 'src/index.js',
    plugins: {
        preVue: [
            replace({
                'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
            }),
            commonjs()
        ],
        vue: {
            css: true,
            template: {
                isProduction: true
            }
        },
        postVue: [
            buble()
        ]
    }
};

const external = [
];

const globals = {
};

const buildFormats = [];

if (!argv.format || argv.format === 'es') {
    const esConfig = {
        ...baseConfig,
        external,
        output: {
            file: 'dist/vue-components.esm.js',
            format: 'esm',
            exports: 'named',
            globals
        },
        plugins: [
            ...baseConfig.plugins.preVue,
            vue(baseConfig.plugins.vue),
            ...baseConfig.plugins.postVue,
            terser({
                output: {
                    ecma: 6
                }
            })
        ]
    };

    buildFormats.push(esConfig);
}

if (!argv.format || argv.format === 'cjs') {
    const umdConfig = {
        ...baseConfig,
        external,
        output: {
            compact: true,
            file: 'dist/vue-components.ssr.js',
            format: 'cjs',
            name: 'VueComponents',
            exports: 'named',
            globals,
        },
        plugins: [
            ...baseConfig.plugins.preVue,
            vue({
                ...baseConfig.plugins.vue,
                template: {
                    ...baseConfig.plugins.vue.template,
                    optimizeSSR: true
                }
            }),
            ...baseConfig.plugins.postVue
        ]
    };

    buildFormats.push(umdConfig);
}

if (!argv.format || argv.format === 'iife') {
    const unpkgConfig = {
        ...baseConfig,
        external,
        output: {
            compact: true,
            file: 'dist/vue-components.min.js',
            format: 'iife',
            name: 'VueComponents',
            exports: 'named',
            globals,
        },
        plugins: [
            ...baseConfig.plugins.preVue,
            vue(baseConfig.plugins.vue),
            ...baseConfig.plugins.postVue,
            terser({
                output: {
                    ecma: 5
                }
            })
        ]
    };

    buildFormats.push(unpkgConfig);
}

export default buildFormats;
```

#### package.json

```
{
  "name": "@company/vue-components",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",

  "main": "dist/vue-components.ssr.js",
  "module": "dist/vue-components.esm.js",
  "unpkg": "dist/vue-components.min.js",

  "files": [
    "dist/*",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "!src/lib-dev.vue"
  ],

  "scripts": {
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production rollup --config build/rollup.config.js",
    "build:ssr": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production rollup --config build/rollup.config.js --format cjs",
    "build:es": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production rollup --config build/rollup.config.js --format es",
    "build:unpkg": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production rollup --config build/rollup.config.js --format iife"
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: What is the `main` entry in your component library `package.json`? For example, here's the Vuex package ~ https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/blob/dev/package.json#L5

Comment: Sorry about that. I have added the package.json information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After trying to deal with this for a couple weeks, I ended up starting the project over with the Vue CLI tool. Using the vue-cli-service build command built the library like I needed. The full command:

```
vue-cli-service build --no-clean --target lib --name vue-components src/index.js
```

The src/index.js is unchanged from my post above